# Avoiding Aspects While Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aspects

I am working on the big project with a number of aspects defined on business classes.
I would like to avoid entering the aspect's code while debugging a code in business classes.
Is there any solution for that?
We are using compile time weaving and maven for compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step filtering might help you. It solves the problem with regular Java code, I'm not sure how it deals with aspects. I expect that if your aspects are in distinct packages then step filter should do the trick.

Reference here -> http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are you using compile or load time weaving?  If you're using LTW, can you disable the weaving agent?

Comment: We are using compile time weaving.

Comment: If you're starting in debug mode, can you recompile without aspect compiling?

Comment: I am using maven for compiling, outside of Eclipse. However, I can use Eclipse for compiling whole project, altogether with aspects. The answer is: I can't recompile without aspect compiling.